# java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty

Tags: jboss7.x

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:117) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:97)
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:83)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:408)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:434)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.mount(EarStructureProcessor.java:223)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.createResourceRoot(EarStructureProcessor.java:242)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.deploy(EarStructureProcessor.java:159)
    ... 6 more
```

i am using JPA 2.0, Ejb 3.0 and for front end jsf 1.2, richfaces 3.3.3, jboss 7.1. Kindly provide some solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the zip file empty, by chance?

Comment: You didn't say which JBoss you are using. Clearly, the error is originating from JBoss's internals.

Comment: Try to open the projet jar or ear file and check if it is really empty

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when deploying an EAR generated by Netbeans, right-click on "Clean" and then on "Deploy".

In my case, Netbeans was repeatedly generating an empty JAR for a sub-project when right-clicking on "Clean and Build" and I was getting the same stack trace than you during the deployment because of this empty JAR.

Follow Riadh's advise above, open your EAR file and look for an invalid and/or empty JAR.